# xcode build error : duplicate symbol when my project has two files with the same name

Tags: iphone, ios

My project has a file named "Reachability.h" (It's very popular, many people use it)

Today I add a framework of others into my project.
I think the frameword has the same file "Reachability.h".

So there is a conflict.

Is it because there is NO namespace in C?
How to avoid this problem?

And here is the log:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in /Volumes/Data/Project/ios/FreeMaster/FreeMaster/src/ThirdParty/Lmmob/LmmobAdWallSDK.framework/LmmobAdWallSDK(Reachability.o) and /Users/lxp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FreeMaster-hdzirfpzangiuqaavvqkrzlccrku/Build/Intermediates/FreeMaster.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FreeMaster.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o for architecture i386
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, there´s no namespace in Objective-C, this problem is often circumvented by using prefixed classes. This is often also the problem when you get "undeserved" rejections from Apple for using private API's you´re not using, e.g. a class called BaseResponse caused us trouble.

Apple reserves the right to have prefixed classes, but in this case you either have to prefix it or rename your class to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain single copy of Reachability files(.h, .m) in your project & remove the extra files. That will solve the issue.

If you want to maintain an extra copy you can create a newgroup and move Reachability files into that folder as in the below screenshot:

[image]

In my finder my files are placed like this:

[image]

Comment: Can it work? The two files are not in the same group and the same folder in Finder. Actually,  one is in my project and the other in in a framework.

Comment: I don't think so. Would u please dumplicate the Reachability.m to the group "New Group" and build again?

Comment: check my edit. I have attached an extra image which is displaying my folder structure in Finder.

Comment: Yes, But the dumplicated files are ".h". How about ".m"? when building the project, every ".m" will generate a ".o" file.

Comment: let me check that case. Give me 2mins.

Answer (score 1):

There is no namesapce or package kind of stuff in objective-c.

Generally if you are same class as in the library, you can delete your class. Import `<yourFramework/Reachability.h>` where ever you use reachability in your code.

Comment: Yes, It's right. But I think a framework should use a class prefix to avoid this problem. So I send email to the maintainer of the framework and they will fix this problem today. Thank you:)

Comment: Welcome.Glad to be of some help :)